# Editing out "Update: Still looking..." style question edits

Tags: discussion, edits

One thing I find unnecessary is the

**Update X:** Help! I'm still waiting for an answer!

style edits.

On one of the questions where I removed this: [Javascript watch event not working on DOM element objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950650), the questioner continued to add it back in after I edited it out. This went back and forth a few (hundred) times.

I tried explaining it to him, but he believes it's "better". I was thinking in terms of other users coming to the question, and the fact that it had only been an hour or so since he asked the question that it was being "Still looking" updated.

I'm just looking for a bit of guidance on if I was doing the "correct" thing? In this case, should I have continuing editing it out?

Comment: After the first couple of reverts you should have flagged it for a moderator.

Comment: Actually, after the *first* revert, you should flag for moderator attention. Don't get into an edit war with someone, even if you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that this kind of behavior is annoying. Looking at the question edits, seems like it was a mini battle between you and the OP.

The community does not encourage greetings/salutations and signatures. There is no point in trying to tell someone more than once. If the person is someone who learns from mistakes, they will learn it the first time or may be the second time. Others, never will learn. Tell them once or twice, if they annoy too much. Raise a flag to the moderators. Moderators know what to do.

By the way, there is always a penalty box for people who never learn from mistakes.

If I were in your shoes, that's what I would have done. `Raise a flag.`

Comment: Thanks. I shall raise a flag in the future :)

Comment: Moderators also have the ability to lock questions, preventing further edits and/or rollbacks. This is very useful in preventing edit wars, and the word of a moderator often holds more "clout" than a high-rep community user in the eyes of a newbie for whatever reason.

Comment: Cody: Fair point. I guess I'm always hesitant to call upon a mod, maybe because I saw it as minor, but I'll be more active with the flags :)

Comment: @APErebus: Well, my general guideline is that if you can solve a problem yourself *without* flagging, you should. So editing the question in the first place is a good idea, and a better option than flagging. But once the person rolls back your edit, it's not worth it to get into an edit war or a comment war or any such thing. In that case, there's nothing more you can do as a regular user, and you need a mod to step in. That is, of course, what they're for. :-)